# Cannot access web3 object with typescript and ethereum

Tags: angular, typescript, ethereum

I started a new project from scratch with angular 2 and typescript with:

```
ng new myProject
```

Then I installed web3 (for ethereum) with

```
npm install web3
```

In the head of index.html, I added:

```
<script src="node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

This path seems OK since I have no error (if I change one char I have an error).
In the doc:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3
I found this: Use the web3 object directly from global namespace:
console.log(web3);
But web3 is not defined.
How can I get this object ?
NOTE: In the background I started geth --testnet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to instantiate it first. Tested with JavaScript:

```
var web3 = new Web3();
window.console.log(web3);
> Object { _requestManager: Object, currentProvider: undefined, eth: 
    Object, db: Object, shh: Object, net: Object, personal: Object, bzz: 
    Object, settings: Object, version: Object, 2 more… }
```

I have no experience with TypeScript though, but you get the idea. web3js is providing the library, and you need to initialize it to work with. It's basically the first line of the linked documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it but half of the time the transpiler will throw an error while transpiling the code.
What i did is getting the web3 object explicit out of the window object.

```
private getWeb3Provider(): Web3 {
if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
  return new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  this.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
  return this.web3;
}}
```

And in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
    this.name = 'Web3 Service';
    console.log(`${this.name}: initialized...`);
    this.web3 = this.getWeb3Provider();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object from the Window object like this:

```
var web3: any = window["web3"];
var Web3: any = window["Web3"];
var web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
this.contract = web3.eth.contract(this.contractAbi).at(this.contractAddress);
```